# Merge tag [google-voice-actions] into [voice-command]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-cleanup, tag-synonyms

I propose that [google-voice-actions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-voice-actions) is marked as a synonym for [voice-command](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-command). The former currently has 10 questions, the latter has 50 questions.

Further, I suggest that [voice-command](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-command) is renamed to plural [voice-commands](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-commands) because that's the usual SE style.

Comment: These tags seem more like they just need to be cleaned up to ensure they're being used properly. Some devices have a "Voice Commands" app, but it's *different* from Google's Voice Actions, which is a very specific implementation of voice-driven commands. There are also third-party apps (e.g. [Dragon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuance.balerion) and such) on the Play Store. I'm not sure I'm convinced they should be merged/synonymized.

Comment: I fully agree with eldarerathis: there are far more voice-control apps out there. As they are often called "Voice Assistants": Maybe we we rather introduce a `voice-assistants` tag, and disambiguising `voice-command(s)`?